# bash alias for creating .bup file copies of multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, files, wildcards, cp

I have my own custom .bashrc file.
I practice my coding a lot so I use raw text and JDK.

I use "shopt -s extglob".

I need to create .bup copy of each file (non-recursively) and kill them after work done.

So I did:

```
alias do_bups='cp ./!(*.bup) ./*.bup'
alias do_bups_clear='rm ./*.bup'
```

What happens:

```
cp: target './*.bup' is not a directory
```

How to copy files adding postfix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
for f in ./!(*.bup); do
    cp "$f" "$f.bup"
done
```

A somewhat safer way:

```
for f in ./!(*.bup); do
    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
        cp -i "$f" "$f.bup"
    fi
done
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! But what if I want to make them hidden? I mean like .*.bup. Adding dot just make them be saved ../

Comment: @Napoleon then add that to the target pattern. `cp -i "$f" ".$f.bup"`

Comment: Ahh, I have edited in wrong place. Cheers!